# How can I pass a GoogleAccountCredential across activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-sheets, google-oauth

I finally figured out the whole Google Sheets OAuth access enchilada, but I ended up with a unwieldy class that does the authorization and the actual data get/update. So I was hoping I can split this in two and put the credential related code into one activity (that I would call via startActivity) and do all the actual read/write to the Google Spreadsheet in the other activity (via AsyncTask).
But it looks like I would need to pass the GoogleAccountCredential across, would I ?
i.e. when I start my AsyncTask with the below, it seems to choke on the missing credential:

```html
    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService = null;

        MakeRequestTask(Context context,GoogleAccountCredential credential) {

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
```

I see this in logcat:

```html
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err: {
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:     "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:     "reason" : "forbidden"
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:   } ],
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:   "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err:   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
04-21 21:27:44.505 13432-13555/com.mairyu.app.lingoflash W/System.err: }
```

I guess I can simply merge the code back together, but I'm curious whether I approach this wrong and whether I misunderstood the problem that causes the error.

Comment: did you get solution for your requirement?

Comment: nope, simply kept it together in a single class for now ...